# Virtual populate with localField and foreignField as arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two schemas, schema1 and schema2. schema1 has the following fields:

```
schema1: {
  style: {
    type: String,
    enum: Object.values(STYLE_TYPES),
    default: STYLE_TYPES.GENRES
  },
  subStyleName: { type: String, default: '' }
};

schema2: {
  id: { type: String, default: '' },
  musicGenreStyleIds: [{ type: String, default: '' }],
  genresStyleIds: [{ type: String, default: '' }],
  storiesStyleIds: [{ type: String, default: '' }],
};
```

I want to create a populate virtual field on schema2 that references schema1. The virtual field should use the id field from schema2 to match documents in schema1 where style matches any of the following fields: musicGenreStyleIds, genresStyleIds, storiesStyleIds, moodsStyleIds, instrumentsStyleIds, documentaryStyleIds, trailersStyleIds, videoGamesStyleIds.

I tried the following:

```
schema2.virtual('nameOfVirtual', {
  localField: 'id',
  foreignField: [
    'musicGenreStyleIds',
    'genresStyleIds',
    'storiesStyleIds',
    'moodsStyleIds',
    'instrumentsStyleIds',
    'documentaryStyleIds',
    'trailersStyleIds',
    'videoGamesStyleIds',
  ],
  ref: schema1,
  justOne: false,
});
```

But TypeScript throws an error. I'm using Mongoose 6.3.6, and I also tried with 7.0.4. Here's a screenshot of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQKDd.png)